# Modifying delete order function in POS odoo using javascript

Tags: javascript, odoo-13, point-of-sale

I want to modify this " minus button " in such a way that if the user click on generate token this button become disabled for that order
In simple words, the user who generated a token for his/her order cannot delete their current token.[UI of POS with added widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcJxy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came up with some temporary  fixes, but its not the solution:

Ok basically i did this

```
PosBaseWidget.include({

          init: function(parent, options) {
            this._super(parent, options);

        },
        get_order_by_uid: function(uid) {
        var orders = this.pos.get_order_list();
        for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++) {
            if (orders[i].uid === uid) {
//                 this.pos.get_order().token_number=Token;
                return orders[i];
            }
        }
        return undefined;
    },
        deleteorder_click_handler: function(event, $el) {
            var self  = this;
            var order = this.pos.get_order();

            if (!order) {
                return;
            } else if ( !order.is_empty() ){

                this.gui.show_popup('confirm',{
                    'title': _t('Destroy Current Order ?'),
                    'body': _t('You will lose any data associated with the current order'),
                    confirm: function(){
                        self.pos.delete_current_order();
                    },
                });
            } else {
                this.pos.delete_current_order();
            }
        },
          renderElement: function(){
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            this.$('.order-button.select-order').click(function(event){

            });
            this.$('.neworder-button').click(function(event){
                self.neworder_click_handler(event,$(this));
            });
            this.$('.deleteorder-button').click(function(event){
                if(Token == null )
               {
                    self.deleteorder_click_handler(event,$(this));

               }
                else
                {
                    self.neworder_click_handler(event,$(this));
                      this.pos.get_order().order_progress="In progress";

                }
            });

        }

});

where 
     var PosBaseWidget = require('point_of_sale.BaseWidget');
     var Token = Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1000);
```

token is actually helping here to assign random unique number to each order in current session
It just a **temporary fix** to my issue and its also arises some new issues *like " new order button [+ signed button] creates two orders on one click". *

As new to odoo and alien to its javascript( not regular javascript )

> i am working on the module to improve this everyday. Will be updating
> after finding more durable fix to my question.Advice,Tips,Opinions and
> suggestions are highly appreciated.